# Why is it possible to delete my own post with other's contribution?

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts, self-delete

I thought that even if for the question writer, it's the most impolite thing to delete own question with other's elaborated answers. Since the question has posted, every participants are able to improve the question via comments, edits, and answers, but who decides to delete one is the writer.

What I want to say is, I think that after someone has posted a question and be helped by others, the question is *no longer owned* by its original writer.

Why the writer can freely delete her own post?

Comment: Per our deletion FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), the system won't let authors delete their questions if it has an upvoted answer or multiple answers. Are you referring to the edge case where authors delete their question right after receiving an answer, with no chance for it to be upvoted?

Comment: I didn't suppose the situation, but that case would be a problem too, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An asker can only delete their question until it has an upvoted or accepted answer, multiple answers or an answer with an awarded bounty..

After that question deletion requires moderator or staff privileges.